# Query to find best match

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have 2 tables as such:

```
Table1                               Table2
+----------+--------+----------+     +--------+---------+-------+
| Customer | Part # | Modifier |     | Part # | Modifer | Value |
+----------+--------+----------+     +--------+---------+-------+
| Fred     |      1 | XYZ      |     |      1 | Null    | 1.5   |
| Fred     |      2 | ABC      |     |      1 | GHI     | 2.0   |
| Fred     |      2 | DEF      |     |      2 | Null    | 3.0   |
| Fred     |      2 | GHI      |     |      2 | ABC     | 3.1   |
| Fred     |      3 | ABC      |     |      2 | DEF     | 3.2   |
| Fred     |      3 | XYZ      |     |      3 | Null    | 8.0   |
| Fred     |      4 | ABC      |     |      4 | Null    | 10.0  |
| Lucy     |      1 | GHI      |     |      5 | Null    | 4.0   |
| Lucy     |      5 | DEF      |     |      5 | ABC     | 4.5   |
| Lucy     |      4 | Null     |     |      5 | DEF     | 4.7   |
+----------+--------+----------+     +--------+---------+-------+
```

ABC, DEF, and GHI are guaranteed to be the only modifiers in Table2 so XYZ can be ignored for the purposes of Table2. I wish to create a query that joins Table1 to Table2 with only 1 result per customer/Part # so the results of the join would be:

```
+----------+--------+-------+
| Customer | Part # | Value |
+----------+--------+-------+
| Fred     |      1 | 1.5   |
| Fred     |      2 | 3.0   |
| Fred     |      3 | 8.0   |
| Fred     |      4 | 10.0  |
| Lucy     |      1 | 2.0   |
| Lucy     |      5 | 4.7   |
| Lucy     |      4 | 10.0  |
+----------+--------+-------+
```

The rules are that only 1 modifier (of ABC, DEF, GHI) is allowed per part # per customer. So the Fred, part #2 is an error condition and should return the value for the Null modifier or 3.0. If a modifier other than 1 of the 3 is used, it's treated as if there were no modifier (or Null). Basically, the value for the Null modifier should always be returned unless there is a single relevant modifier (ABC, DEF, GHI) and that modifier is defined for the part #.

I don't which direction I should go. Join to Table2 more than once with difference conditions? Use OVER/PARTITION BY to somehow rank the results and choose the top one? I tried a couple of different solutions, but always seem to leave one of the conditions out.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can default the values using:

```
select t1.*, coalesce(t2.value, t2null.value) as value
from table1 t1 left join
     table2 t2
     on t1.part = t2.part and
        t1.modifier = t2.modifier left join
     table2 t2null
     on t1.part = t2null.part and
        t2null.modifier is null;
```

Then to get one per customer/part:

```
select t.*
from (select t1.*, coalesce(t2.value, t2null.value) as value,
             row_number() over (partition by t1.customer, t1.part
                                order by (case when t2.value is not null then 1 else 2 end)
                               ) as seqnum
      from (select t1.*, 
                   sum(case when part in ('ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI') then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by customer) as cnt
            from table1 t1
           ) t1 left join
           table2 t2
           on t1.part = t2.part and
              t1.modifier = t2.modifier and
              t1.cnt = 1 left join
           table2 t2null
           on t1.part = t2null.part and
              t2null.modifier is null
      ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. This gets me much closer, however I have a couple of assumptions (errors?) and a question.
1. I assume that the 2nd 'on' clause in the 1st query should be referencing t2null instead of just t2. Correct?
2. I assume that there should be a where clause on the 2nd query to just get the first item in each set. Is this also correct?
Also, this query doesn't seen to handle the Fred/2 case. Is there a way to get the value from the null modifier into that record?

Comment: @Tom . . . You are right about the query stuff and it is now fixed.  I also modified the query to handle the Fred/2 case.

Comment: That looks perfect. Thanks again for the help!